# Load a rails page after foreman start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, sharetribe

I'm new to web development. I'm trying to follow the instructions here to set up a local instance of the sharetribe.com website: https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe

I've followed all the steps under "Setting up the development environment" without any issues, but when I get to the end, I'm supposed to "Open a browser and go to the server URL (e.g. http://lvh.me:3000)"

At that URL, I get "This site can’t be reached." Is my URL supposed to be at a different port on localhost? How do I figure out where my site is at?

Answer (score 1):

Foreman starts the server on 'http://0.0.0.0:5000' by default.
Instead of Foreman, you can also start the rails server with following command:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The IP address prints out in the terminal where you did the "foreman start" command after the line "Rails 5.1.1 application starting in development on"

Mine was http://0.0.0.0:5000 (not that it's 5000 not 3000), then after filling in the information, I was redirected to http://[my marketplace name].lvh.me:3000/ and I had to change that to 5000 to see the marketplace. Huzzah!